# Extend the Magento API as it returns the products list as if we give category ID

Tags: magento, oauth, oauth-2.0, magento-1.7, magento-1.4

How to extend the magento API's?? I want it as if i give the category ID it has to bring the products in that category and it has to return the data in JSON format. So for this, what are all the API's should be extended??? What are the files that are need to be modified for this??

Is it possible to bring the list of products by giving the category ID? If yes, Please explain it briefly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/Resources/Products/products.html) url thoroughly we get most of the answer.
You can get product list by category id in this way

```
magentohost/api/rest/products?category_id=5
```

Comment: Yes.. it works. But it returns in XML format.. I need it in JSON format for ajax calls..

Comment: plz ask the question in stackoverflow somebody might have your required answer.

Comment: @chanz how to get all category listings like product list?

Comment: @chanz & john how to get category id by using category name in magento rest oauth api?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/Resources/Products/product_categories.html here you can find the rest api Uri For categories, But what you are looking for I guess this functionality is not present you have to customized if  you want that features.

Comment: @chanz We want to get all category list but this only return perticular product category. how we customized to use this?.

Comment: @chanz how we get category id by category name using magento rest oauth api.

Answer (score 0):

To get the response in JSON, just add "Accept: application/json" in your header.
If you're using RestClient, click Headers > Custom Header and enter the following:
Name: Accept
Value: application/json